# Correct method to write conditional code in clojure

Tags: clojure

So I am trying to write the below in clojure (Assume all methods below return boolean)

```
def some_method(a, b)
  if (call_this_method() )
    then_call_this_method()
  else
    new_method()
end
```

What I got was this:

```
(defn some-method [a b]
  (if (call_this_method) 
   :then (then-call-this-method) 
   :else (new-method)))
```

I am pretty new to clojure so am not sure if this feels like the correct manner to solve this. Is there a different approach?

Comment: There are examples at clojuredocs.org, start from http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/if

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if` basically takes 3 params, [condition what-to-run-if-true optional-run-if-false]

```
(defn some-method
    "My function does ..."
    [ a b ] 
    (if (call-this-method)
        (then-call-this-method)
        (new-method)))
```

Comment: If you need several clauses in either `then` or `else` branch use `(do (function1) (function2))`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `if` in clojure as well

```
(if test then-code else-code)
```

Or `cond` which is more like switch

```
(cond
    test-A run-if-A
    test-B run-if-B
    ...
    :else else-code)
```

And if you wanted to do something like

```
 if(foo) bar;
```

Then you would write

```
 (when foo bar)
```